# Is there an equivelent to the "polymer-ready" event in Polymer 1.0?

Tags: polymer-1.0

I need to know when I can begin using my custom Polymer elements programmatically. The elements are still `undefined` even in my `window.onload` handler.  Is there an established way of doing this correctly with Polymer 1.0?

-Edit-

I see there is a downvote, so let me clarify the issue.  I have the following custom element definition:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="element-one">
    <style>
        :host { display: block; background-color: blue; }
    </style>
    <template>
        <h1>Element One</h1>
        <content></content>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
var ElementOne = Polymer({
    is: "element-one"
});
</script>
```

I then import this in my `index.html`:

```
<link rel="import" href="elements/element-one/element-one.html">
```

And at the bottom of `index.html`, before the `</body>` tag, I try to instantiate a `ElementOne` element:

```
<script>
    console.log(typeof ElementOne); // undefined
    var el = new ElementOne(); // fails, obviously

    // try on window load
    window.onload = function () {
        console.log(typeof ElementOne); // undefined
    };
</script>
```

I should note that this issue occurs in the latest Firefox and IE 10/11, but not in Chrome.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use [WebComponentsReady](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#webcomponentsready) event:

```
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function(e) {
...
});
```