# How to get the first paper-item in Polymer 1.0 using tagName?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I created dinamically paper-item's and I want to get the first one when the page is loaded. This paper-item's where created inside a dom-repeat like this:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{menu.Options}}" as="sub" id="iron_pages_app_2">
    <paper-item on-tap="funcion" class="olakease"><span>{{sub.Name}}</span></paper-item>
</template>
```

To get what I want, I tried using this on the ready and attached functions, but doesn't work:

```
attached: function () {
    this.async(function () {
      console.log("______________________________________________________");
      var htmlCollection = document.getElementById("controlAppMenu").getElementsByTagName("paper-item");
      console.log("___________________htmlCollection___________________________________");
      console.log(htmlCollection);
      console.log("______________________________________________________");
      var className = this.getElementsByClassName('olakease');
      console.log("___________________getElementsByClassName___________________________________");
      console.log(className);
      console.log("______________________________________________________");
      console.log(htmlCollection.length) //show 0
      console.log(elements.length) //show 13
    });
}
```

Console shows:
[image: why htmlCollection.length is 0?][image: why this cant be accessed using javascrip?][image: why this works?]

Why getElementsByClassName works and getElementsByTagName don´t? 
In my case, I need to get the first paper-input, and use classes dont look good to me. Anyone can help me? I hope you can understand my poor English!

### Edit

This is the code where I create my papaer-item:

```
<div id="controlAppMenu">
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{menu.Options}}" as="menu" id="iron_pages_app">
    <paper-item on-tap="toggle" pos="{{index}}" referencia$="{{menu.Id}}"><iron-icon icon="{{menu.Icon}}"></iron-icon><span>{{menu.Name}}</span></paper-item>
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{hasMenu(menu.Options)}}">
        <iron-collapse id="{{menu.Id}}" class="ironCollapseClass">
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{menu.Options}}" as="sub" id="iron_pages_app_2">
                <paper-item on-tap="funcion" padre$="{{menu.Id}}" class="olakease"><span style="padding-left: 3em">{{sub.Name}}</span></paper-item>
            </template>
        </iron-collapse>
     </template>
</template>
</div>
```

### Edit 2

I made ​​a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cuxuco/1/edit?html,console,output) using zerodevx's example. But I can not make it work as I want. When the attached function is called means I can use dom elements, right?
My menus are generated using an iron-ajax request in ready´s function, so I have another question, what function is called first, attached function or iron-ajax request function? (Documentation says [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#initialization-order) first ready function, then attached function) I think maybe here is the real problem in this situation. Thanks!

Comment: Show us your code where you `controlAppMenu` element is

Comment: As you can see @leo.fcx I have two dom-repeats to add elements to dom, this works fine, the problem is that I need the first one to set as active

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After one and a half day of researching, I finally found a solution [here](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#webcomponentsready) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30667685/is-there-an-equivelent-to-the-polymer-ready-event-in-polymer-1-0). I need to call 'webcomponentsready' event to use all elements created.

```
var self = this;
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function(e) {
    // imports are loaded and elements have been registered
    console.log('Components are ready');
    var p = self.getElementsByTagName("paper-item");
    console.log(p);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your `dom-repeat` in a container:

```
<div id="container">
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{menu.Options}}" as="sub" id="iron_pages_app_2">
    <paper-item on-tap="funcion" class="olakease"><span>{{sub.Name}}</span></paper-item>
  </template>
</div>
```

Access the first `paper-item` inside container by:

```
this.$.container.querySelectorAll("paper-item")[0]
```

In general, when building Polymer components, avoid using vanilla javascript document-level stuff like `document.getElementById` or `document.getElementByClassName`. Instead, use Polymer stuff like `this.$` or `this.$$()` or `Polymer.dom(this)` when accessing template nodes.

You save yourself a lot of trouble when piercing between light/shady/shadow DOM.

**UPDATE 1**

You can place the call inside `attached` callback but wrap the call with an `async` to ensure that the query runs only **after** microtasks are complete - in this case, the actual rendering of the `dom-repeat` template itself.

```
  <dom-module id="x-test">
    <template>
      <div id="container">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{menu.Options}}" as="sub" id="iron_pages_app_2">
           <paper-item on-tap="funcion" class="olakease"><span>{{sub.Name}}</span></paper-item>
        </template>
      </div>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      ...
      attached: function () {
        this.async(function () {
          var node = this.$.container.querySelectorAll("paper-item")[0];
          console.log(node);
        });
      }
      ...
    });
  </script>
```

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/kovohuwuce/edit?html,console,output

Comment: This answer works when I try to access template nodes after dom is ready and attached, for example if I use $0.querySelectorAll('paper-item') in console after the page is loaded I can get all nodes, but if I try to get this nodes in the polymer's attached method doesn´t work. I want to get the first element o any element to set it with an active class after the page is loaded. By the way thanks for the reply.

Comment: Are you using `dom-repeat` inside an auto-binding template? Polymer's `attached` callback guarantees that the component's light dom is created, and that component is attached into the main document, so you can definitely query nodes from there.

Comment: Yes, I think the same as you , but I couldn't make it work that way. I only get an empty array and I don´t know why.

Comment: My bad - I've updated my answer. When `attached` is called, data is bound, light dom nodes are attached but shadow nodes (nested templates like your `dom-repeat`) might still be rendering. So wrap your query in an `async()` to ensure it is called only after microtasks are completed.